# array foreach problem

Tags: php, foreach

I am having some problem with `foreach` statement.Though the input to `foreach` statement is an array, it says

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

and my code looks like this

```
foreach($res_array as $res)
     {
       foreach($res as $re)
       {
           echo $re['shortUrl'];
       }
     }
```

and my array looks like this

```
Array ( [errorCode] => 0 [errorMessage] => [results] => Array ( [http://www.telegraph.co.uk/earth/earthpicturegalleries/5966251/The-weirdest-animals-on-Planet-Earth.html?image=5] => Array ( [hash] => 2qNNV6 [shortUrl] => http://su.pr/2qNNV6 ) ) [statusCode] => OK )
```

I am getting that error for the second foreach. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: More information please i.e. What Language/platform/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to loop over `$res_array['results']`, rather than `$res_array`. You shouldn't need to nest your foreach loops either.

It looks like the result array contains some additional information, so you might want to do something like (untested):

```
$res_array = GetResultsFromSomewhere();

if ($res_array['errorCode']) {
    die("Error {$res_array['errorCode']}: {$res_array['errorMessage']}");
}

foreach ($res_array['results'] as $url => $item) {
    echo $item['shortUrl'];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because not every element of your original array is itself an array. For instance, you have `errorCode` which is an integer, thus throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

in your example each value of the top array is also an array. It doesn't seem to be correct from your example. before performing second foreach loop, you need to [check whether element is an array](http://dcos.php.net/is_array).

Answer (score 0):

You have an array not all its element are array, so you have first to check first each element if it is an array or not then fetch it.

```
<?php
foreach($res_array as $res)
     {
      if(is_array($res))
       foreach($res as $re)
        {
           echo $re['shortUrl'];
        }
     }
?>
```